# How to write generic function in Kotlin for serialization data

Tags: kotlin, generics, serialization

I'm tryna write function for program with Ktor. I need to pass to parameters of the functions generic type of data and after serialization I need to get this data back. How to make it?

I write this one, but it not work.

```
sealed class ServiceResult<out T : Any> {
     @Serializable
     data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : ServiceResult<T>()
     @Serializable
     data class Error<out T : Any>(val error: T) : ServiceResult<T>()
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> serializeServiceResult(x: ServiceResult<T>): Pair<String, KClass<T>> = when (x) {
     is ServiceResult.Success -> Pair(Json.encodeToString(x.data), T::class)
     is ServiceResult.Error -> Pair("Error occurred with ${T::class}", T::class)
}
```

Example result that I wanna get:

```
class MainTest {

@Test
fun booleanTest() {
    val serverAnswer = serializeServiceResult(ServiceResult.Success(true))
    assert(serverAnswer.first == true) // type Boolean
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your serialized result is a String, which you cannot compare to a Boolean. You need to compare it to another String:

```
assert(serverAnswer.first == Json.encodeToString(true))
```

You could use an extension function if you do this repeatedly:

```
inline fun <reified T> assertEqualsJson(value: String, expect: T) =
    assert(value == Json.encodeToString(expect))

//...

assertEqualsJson(serverAnswer.first, true)
```